# Closure function is appending all index from loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am trying to append index value to element using the loop. i made a `closure` to avoid the multiple index appended.

but my `closure` function still adding the multiple(previous) index to `dom`

```
    var $newdiv = $('.div').clone().removeClass('div').addClass('show')
    $col = $('<div />');
   var add = function () {
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
        (function x (n) {
            return function () { //not working!
                $newdiv.find($('a span').append(n)).end().clone().appendTo($col);
            }();
        }(i));
    }

}

$col.appendTo('#content');
$('button').click(function () { add()});
$('#content').slimScroll({});
```

[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/L6q58tf9/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code like this. it works fine.

```
var $newdiv = $('.div').clone().removeClass('div').addClass('show')
    $col = $('<div />');
var n = 0;
   var add = function () {
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){
         $newdiv.clone().removeClass('div').addClass('show')
         .find('span').append(n = n < 9 ? '0'+(++n) : ++n).end().clone().appendTo($col);
    }

}

$col.appendTo('#content');
$('button').click(function () { add()});
$('#content').slimScroll({});
```